# Пустая область сбоку на мобильной версии сайта

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap

[image: Пустая область справа]

Не могу понять почему, но образуется такая область в мобильной версии. Прошу помочь, в чем может быть проблема. Спасибо. Ссылка на страницу https://www.ok24pay.com/xchange_BTC_to_ETH/

Comment: добавьте классу .thecontent или .xchangestep1body свойство overflow:hidden;

Comment: @MaxManchak спасибо за ответ, помогло. Еще есть вопрос , на этой же  странице 2 поля "сумма" подряд. Хотелось бы первое поле убрать, но этого я сделать не могу так как у всех полей "Сумма" один и тот же класс. Как я могу сделать это?

Comment: #ajaxobmen1 .obmenfirstright {display:none;} - должно сработать

Comment: @MaxManchak возможно неправильно объяснил. Тогда не первый, а второй из трех,  https://www.ok24pay.com/xchange_SBERRUB_to_PMUSD/ пусть будет эта страница. Спсибо

Comment: попробуйте следующее #ajaxobmen2 .obmenfirstblock:first-child .obmenfirstright {display:none;}

Comment: @MaxManchak Спасибо) Отлично) Можешь помочь сделать тоже самое на комп.версии .woblock .wosummblock:first-child .wosummtitle {
    display: none;
}
пробовал так, но не получилось

Comment: .woblock.getting .wosummblock:first-child .wosummtitle,  .woblock.getting .wosummblock:first-child  .wosumminput {display:none}

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82291/discussion-between-emil-rotatew-and-max-manchak).